# VBA Alternative to For Each

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently using a lot of `For ... Each` loops in my code which is slowing it down a lot, is there a faster approach?

I have heard I could copy the range to an array and edit the array and paste it back but im having a few problems with editing each cell in the array.

Here is the current for each code I am using - Thanks.

```
Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Sheets("sheet1").UsedRange
        cell.Value = cell.Value
Next cell
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along these lines:

```
Dim aCells As Variant
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long

aCells = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange

' Now do something with the array;
' We'll debug.print the contents of each element
'   to verify that it matches the cells in the sheet
For x = 1 To UBound(aCells, 1)
  For y = 1 To UBound(aCells, 2)
    Debug.Print aCells(x, y)
  Next
Next
```

Comment: +1 - this is my usual attempt too - and to put them back onto the sheet: `Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange = aCells`

Comment: Hi Steve, I have a loop that trims the cell of white space, I have tried Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim (aCells(x, y)) but I still seem to get problems. Could you help me out with that?

Comment: Sam, in the loop, just put in aCells(x, y) = trim(aCells(x, y)) and then, as Jook suggested, after the loop, put it back to the sheet.  ALSO, maybe just use Excel's find / Replace feature - Replace 2 spaces with one space... Again, there are many ways to get a specific result, the question is which would be most efficient

Answer (score 3):

Try this - MUCH faster and more efficient:

```
Sheets("sheet1").UsedRange.Value = Sheets("sheet1").UsedRange.Value
```

Comment: sarcasm? replacing your data with itself does not have to be work at all. However, I think the main idea was an alternative way to change multiple cells and not to use `For Each` for that.

Comment: Jook - I agree with you and with Steve's solution... HOWEVER for specific cases it is better to use Excel's native code such as setting values for a range or setting formulas for an entire range all at once... Sam, if you post a few more examples of what you want to accomplish, maybe that would help, BUT if your question is simply about how to make the looping more efficient, then Steve's response would be the way I would do it too.

Comment: Thanks John, the way you have done it is perfect for this situation and is the method I have used however in a more general sense I agree that Steves method is better. Thank you for your help, I have added a bit more in the comment of steves answer if you could be of any help with that aswell that would be amazing.

Comment: +1 exactly what was requested. A manipulation needs an array, a conversion from formulae to values should be done as above